# How to resize Cutom Buttons and Labels according to iphone 4?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uilabel, retina-display

I have an application containing number of images, custom buttons having images and number of labels.

My problem is to resize those buttons,images and labels according to iphone 4 as wel as iphone 3.

i know that images named @2x are used for high resolution, but I cant find any way to enlarge my custom buttons and labels and also those images which didn't define in code.

how do I get their exact position??

Comment: I am a beginner and dont know how to sort out the above problem, Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although screen resolution of iPhone is 640x960, screen dimensions for UIKit are still 320x480 so normally you don't need to adjust coordinates for your UI elements specifically for iPhone4.

If you have '@2x' images for retina display then system will automatically draw them appropriately in the frame you had for normal display.

Comment: Thanks. But I have created a image with this code: self.imageViewLogo.frame = CGRectMake(123, 205, 250, 66); then how it can be scale to @2x images CGRectFrame. Please let me clear on that or provide any better suggestion for the same.

Comment: @IphoneDeveloper do you have any specific problems with your views? why do you think you need to set different frame for retina display devices?

Comment: I dont have any problem, my application is running successfully on iphone 3, but i dont have iphone4 or xcode 4 to test my application on that, thats why I am little bit confused about it, as i told that I am a beginner.

Comment: btw, you can at least test your app on iphone4 simulator - in simulator check hardware/device/iphone(retina)